# how to solve syntax exception in sqlite while using cursor query?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my project, I am using this cursor query:

```
Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, columns, helper.TX_ID + "='" + name + "' AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN '"+ datefrom.from_date + "' AND '"  + dateto.to_date + "'  AND '"+ helper.TX_TYPE +" = '"+"DM", null, helper.TX_NAME, null, null);
```

I get the following exception for my above query:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "DM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, txname, SUM(amount) AS amount, date, txtype FROM transactions WHERE txid='E' AND date BETWEEN '2015-09-06' AND '2015-09-06'  AND 'txtype = 'DM GROUP BY txname
```

Comment: why dont you use `selectionArgs` parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

See this part:

```
AND 'txtype = 'DM GROUP BY txname
```

Should be:

```
AND txtype = 'DM' GROUP BY txname
```

---

The error is here:

```
 AND '"+ helper.TX_TYPE +" = '"+"DM", null,
```

Should be:

```
 AND "+ helper.TX_TYPE +" = 'DM'", null,
```

---

So, fix your rawQuery from this:

```
Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, columns, helper.TX_ID + "='" + name + "' AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN '"+ datefrom.from_date + "' AND '" + dateto.to_date + "' AND '"+ helper.TX_TYPE +" = '"+"DM", null, helper.TX_NAME, null, null);
```

to this:

```
Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, columns, helper.TX_ID + "='" + name + "' AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN '"+ datefrom.from_date + "' AND '" + dateto.to_date + "' AND "+ helper.TX_TYPE +" = 'DM'", null, helper.TX_NAME, null, null);
```

**[EDIT]**

Using **bound parameters** (AKA **selectionArgs**) would help you getting rid of the string delimiters:

```
Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, columns, helper.TX_ID + " = ? AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ? AND "+ helper.TX_TYPE + " = ?", new String[]{name, datefrom.from_date, dateto.to_date, "DM"}, helper.TX_NAME, null, null);
```

Comment: can you tell how to do it in the query?

Comment: you are suggesting not to to use `selectionArgs`, that's not good

Comment: that's much better but its too late imho, OP will most likely use his original code duplicating bad patterns